# Unable to upgrade Requests lib Python

Tags: 14.04, package-management, upgrade, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to upgrade Requests lib for Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, but I can't.

If I try to run `sudo pip install requests --upgrade` I get this message:

```
Downloading/unpacking requests from https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919e
  Downloading requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88kB): 88kB downloaded
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from )
Requirement already up-to-date: idna>=2.5,<2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requ)
Requirement already up-to-date: chardet>=3.0.2,<3.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (fr)
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3>=1.21.1,<1.23 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (fr)
Installing collected packages: requests
   Found existing installation: requests 2.2.1
   Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

If I try to unistall it to then install it again:`sudo pip uninstall requests`:

```
Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first try this

```
sudo -i pip install --upgrade requests
```

if that doesn't work then below one

uninstall your pip and install the latest one hope this may solve the issue

uninstall - `sudo pip uninstall pip`

reinstall  `sudo apt install python-pip`

Comment: Worked with 'sudo -i pip install --upgrade requests'.  Thank you!